# Hosting with Java and VNC support?

Tags: java, linux, vnc

I am new to linux and java, I have developed an application with Java EE 5 want to host it on linux platform, firstly which flavour should I use CentOS/Ubuntu?
which architecture? 32 bit/ 64bit?

and I want vnc support because I cant work on ssh.

Comment: Why not ssh?  I've never heard of a host providing vnc support.

Comment: Titles are _brief_ summaries of your questions, so please try to make them as short as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend 64-bit on a server.  As for CentOS/Ubuntu, I would recommend Ubuntu because I prefer debian-based systems to Red Hat-based systems (for many reasons).

[This place](http://www.eapps.com/applications/glassfish-hosting.php) looks to have everything you need, including the vnc option.  And they seem to have [great uptime and good reviews](http://www.webhostingstuff.com/company/eApps.html).  I have no personally experience with offsite hosting Java apps, though.

I have hosted static and php websites on [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com).  I've heard some people complain about GoDaddy, but they were always great for me and at the time, I was comparing prices and GoDaddy was a great value.   They have shared hosting plans that include java.  Another host that I always hear great things about is [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/index.php).

A couple other hosts I've heard about that also have dedicated hosting are [Site5](http://www.site5.com) and [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/).  I would trust anyone of these hosts with my website.  You just have to look and see who has the options you want at the best price.

Comment: Why would you blindly recommend that? Yes, for some use cases, 64-bit architecture is needed, but for many workloads, it's not needed, and you can make better use of the available system RAM with 32-bit.

Comment: 64-bit has pretty much matured to where that is no longer true.  A few desktop applications may still have 64-bit issues, but even that is rare.  64-bit is going to better utilize your server hardware and provide more room for growth.